# How to include the 'xxx_stub.h' file generated from a haskell source file when building with Stack

Tags: c, haskell, build, ffi, haskell-stack

Building with Stack, I have a `lib.hs` in the `src/` and a `main.c` in the `app/`. When building, the `lib_stub.h` is generated under `.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build`.

To include this file in `main.c`, I either write a complete absolute path behind the `#include` directive or, before a manual second pass, manually copy the `lib_stub.h` file to `app/`, which is kind of stupid.

Is there a better way?

More infomation:

My `package.yaml` looks like

```
name:                mylib
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "gituser/mylib"
license:             BSD3
author:              "Author name here"
maintainer:          "example@example.com"
copyright:           "2018 Author name here"

extra-source-files:
- README.md
- ChangeLog.md

# Metadata used when publishing your package
# synopsis:            Short description of your package
# category:            Web

# To avoid duplicated efforts in documentation and dealing with the
# complications of embedding Haddock markup inside cabal files, it is
# common to point users to the README.md file.
description:         Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/gituser/mylib#readme>

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

library:
  source-dirs: src
  dependencies:
  - free
  - mtl

executables:
  cont-demo:
    main:                main.c
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    # - -rtsopts
    # - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - mylib

tests:
  mylib-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - mylib
```

And my path structure looks like

```
.
├── app
│   ├── MyLib_stub.h
│   └── main.c
├── ChangeLog.md
├── mylib.cabal
├── LICENSE
├── package.yaml
├── README.md
├── Setup.hs
├── src
│   └── MyLib.hs
├── stack.yaml
└── test
    └── Spec.hs
```

where `app/MyLib_stub.h` is manually copied, not automatically placed there.

Comment: maybe you want to pass the path to the include files as an argument to your favourite compiler?

Comment: But the include path may vary if my project is moved to another path. This may happen, for example, when 'git clone'-ed by another one.

Comment: @arrowd I just drop the `main.c` file in the `app/`, and then edit the `package.yaml` to have the entries like `main: main.c`. And Stack manages to build `main.c` for me. I didn't think too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really like it if Stack had some proper way of doing this, but AFAIK it doesn't.

What I currently do in a project with similar requirements is, instead of *copying* the `_stub.h` file to a more convenient location, I *symlink* it. This only needs to be done once, the symlink can be put under version control, and then updates to the `LONG_PATH/....h` file will automatically show up in the convenience one.

```
$ ln -s dist/build/bla/bla/long/path/MyLib_stub.h app/MyLib_stub.h
$ git add app/MyLib_stub.h
```

I'm afraid this will not work on Windows, but there's probably a similar alternative for that.

Comment: Thanks. This is clever and convenient enough. But when I `git clone` the project from an ubuntu to a mac, I have to set this symbolic link again because it won't be a `x86_64-linux` any more. Just wondering if there is any `auto-variable` for Stack to refer to its `build/` path.